# with complexity better than quadratic, how to find if there is two elements in an array there sum equal a passed value

Tags: algorithm

Not sure if I should ask this here or in mathematics but I have a solution for this problem I want to understand why does it really work.
Given an array of values design an algorithm better than n^2 to find if the array contains two elements their sum equal passed value s

> e.g. for array{5,9,1,3} s = 6 returns true  s = 7 returns false

```
solution for s = 6
1)  Subtract s/2 thus the array become {2,6,-1,1}

2)  Sort based on absolute values in non-decreasing order, it become {-1,1,2,6}

3)  Search if there two consecutive numbers their sum = s/2 then the algorithm return true (in this case 1 + 2 = s/2 thus true)
```

> I think the complexity here is nlogn for sort + n for consecutive
>   search = nlogn

Any idea why does this work? is there a math theroem behind this or something?

Comment: There is an error in solution example: 1)  Subtract s/2 thus the array become **{2,6,-2,1}**. Also as @ScottHunter noticed in he's answer, there should be two elements with different signs but with same values in sorted, so point 3 isn't correct, too.

Comment: @A.Chubarov: Actually, its {2,6,-2,0}.

Comment: @ScottHunter, yep, my bad. The main point is that on step 2 it will have consecutive -2, 2, which allows us to restore original values, which give us a sum = 6: 5 + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By subtracting s/2 from all values, you transform the problem into finding pairs that sum to 0 (if a+b=s, then (a-s/2)+(b-s/2)=s-s/2-s/2=0), which means finding values that have the same absolute value but different signs.  Sorting on absolute value will places said values next to one another.

Note that this means, unless you transcribed it wrong, that the algorithm does *not* work, since it is looking for adjacent values that sum to s/2.

Also, the result of step 1 in your example should be {2,6,-2,0}, making step 2 {0,-2,2,6}, which has no adjacent pairs that sum to s/2 but does have one that sums to 0.

Comment: i did modify it to return true if there exist two pairs with equal absolute values and it worked
thanks, this helped

Comment: Note that they have to have equal absolute values but *also* opposite signs: they have to sum to 0.

Answer (score 2):

This task can be solved with O(n) time complexity but with additional O(n) memory space. The idea is to put array elements to a some kind of hash table and in loop verify if hash table contains s-i element. Here C# implementation

```c#
    public static bool ExistsPairSum(int[] array, int s)
    {
        var dict = new HashSet<int>(array);
        foreach (var i in array)
        {
            if (dict.Contains(s - i))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```